# Firebase: Return `.key()` in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Is there a way to print the `.key()` of an item in an `ng-repeat`. My `providers` object looks like this.

```
"providers" : {
  "provider1" : { "name" : "The Whittington Hospital" },
  "provider2" : { "name" : "Homerton Hospital" },
  ...
},
```

Is there a way to print an `ng-repeat` of the `.key()` of my item (`provider1`, `provider2`)? Like so:

```
<ul><li ng-repeat="p in providers">print .key() here</li></ul>
```

Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
<ul><li ng-repeat="p in providers">{{ p.$id }}</li></ul>
```